# Localizing Core Data model properties for display

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ios, core-data

I'm working on an iOS project that uses a large and fairly complex data model. Some of the entities in the model have corresponding detail view controllers, which include table views that should display localized names and the corresponding values of certain properties.

I've looked at some of [Apple's documentation for creating a strings file for a managed object model](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005190-SW13), but most of it seems geared toward displaying error messages generated by the SDK rather than accessing localized property names directly.

I created a strings file ("ModelModel.strings") for my model file ("Model.xcdatamodel"), and verified that it is loading correctly by looking at `-localizationDictionary` on my NSManagedObjectModel instance. My question is: how should I access the localized entity and property names in my code? Is there a way to get to them via NSEntityDescription, NSPropertyDescription, etc. or do I have to go through the NSManagedObjectModel every time?

I'm new at localization, so maybe the answer is obvious, but if so, feel free to just give me a nudge in the right direction.

**Update**

Following @ughoavgfhw's answer, I quickly came up with two categories to accomplish what I needed. Gist: https://gist.github.com/910824

NSEntityDescription:

```
@interface NSEntityDescription (LocalizedName)

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *localizedName;

@end

@implementation NSEntityDescription (LocalizedName)

@dynamic localizedName;

- (NSString *)localizedName {
    static NSString *const localizedNameKeyFormat = @"Entity/%@";
    NSString *localizedNameKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:localizedNameKeyFormat, [self name]];
    NSString *localizedName = [[[self managedObjectModel] localizationDictionary] objectForKey:localizedNameKey];
    if (localizedName) {
        return localizedName;
    }
    return [self name];
}

@end
```

NSPropertyDescription:

```
@interface NSPropertyDescription (LocalizedName)

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *localizedName;

@end

@implementation NSPropertyDescription (LocalizedName)

@dynamic localizedName;

- (NSString *)localizedName {
    static NSArray *localizedNameKeyFormats = nil;
    if (!localizedNameKeyFormats) {
        localizedNameKeyFormats = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Property/%@/Entity/%@", @"Property/%@", nil];
    }
    for (NSString *localizedNameKeyFormat in localizedNameKeyFormats) {
        NSString *localizedNameKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:localizedNameKeyFormat, [self name], [[self entity] name]];
        NSString *localizedName = [[[[self entity] managedObjectModel] localizationDictionary] objectForKey:localizedNameKey];
        if (localizedName) {
            return localizedName;
        }
    }
    return [self name];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to get that information provided by apple, but you could implement it yourself. You just need to add categories to NSEntityDescription, etc. which create the identifier and ask for the localized value from the model, and then treat it as if it were built in.

Here is an example NSEntityDescription implementation. For properties, you would do something similar, but you should use both the entity and property name in case multiple entities have properties with the same name (you may also need to use both the entity and property name as keys in your localization file. I don't know if the model will create them automatically).

```
@implementation NSEntityDescription (Localization)
- (NSString *)localizedName {
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Entity/%@", [self name]];
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[self managedObjectModel] localizationDictionary];
    NSString *localizedName = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
    return (localizedName ? localizedName : [self name]);
}
@end
```

Here is a [reference for the keys used in the localizations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001174-SW1).

Comment: Aw. It's disappointing that there isn't a public API for this, but I suppose it's not hard to do manually. Thanks!